# ColdFusion app " Error Executing Database Query. Access denied for user" for RDS mySQL

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, amazon-rds

I have a legacy `Coldfusion` application that I am trying to migrate the local `mySQL` database to `AWS RDS MySQL`.  Migration worked great and setup and test of the data source name `(DSN)` also indicated success.  But the now when the app tries to query the database (just a SELECT statement), I get the following error.:

```
Access denied for user 'foobar'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

The user is the admin user setup on RDS.  I can logon to the `RDS mySQL` server from the command prompt and perform the same query that the app is trying to use; so I know it's not a connectivity thing.

thanks in advance

Comment: Does the user have access to the tables? Can you run the query in something like Toad or dBeaver as the CF user?

Answer (score 0):

From the CLI, remote into the database and check the `GRANTS` on the user `foobar`:

```
show GRANTS for 'foobar';
```

This will [show the user's permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html) and from which `host` they can access those privileges.

The posted error message says the user `foobar` is trying to connect from `%` (anywhere). I'm not sure if AWS allows "anywhere" access to their databases. You might need to update the user's `host` address based on the IP of the CF server. There could also be AWS firewall permissions to be investigated.